Blender 4.2 - Eevee - Problem with glass transparency
I've got a problem with glass transparency in new Blender 4.2 in Eevee. I tried search more informations and solutions but I don't understand this situation.
Of course I read this topic: Transparent Glass Material Eevee Blender version 4.2
But it still not working correctly. Element transparency still does not appear. What could be causing this problem?
I'm testing this version on a 2019 iMac

There's a new short tutorial on transparency in Eevee in 4.2 here which might help.

As the author of the answer you have linked to I have to ask for more information. Theoretically it works like I explained there, so when you say it is still not working correctly it would be helpful to know in which way it is not correct or we need to know your exact settings to find where they might differ to cause the issue. But while I'm typing this comment I see @JohnEason has provided a tutorial link. Maybe this already clears things up.
